# How to zero out inventory in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

I have 1500+ products and 2000+ locations. I have updated the inventory with update inventory wizard in products and also I have processed some delivery orders and internal moves. Now I want to zero out the inventory. I made a script to zero out the inventory. The problem is that it takes too much time to update the inventory to zero as each product can be any where in 2000 locations. Is there any OpenERP function which will return all locations that a product is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Context

To keep the data model simple ([KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) and avoid issues with cache invalidation, OpenERP does not keep a cache of the current inventory of products in each location. This information is obtained by computing the double-entry balance of stock transactions entering and leaving each stock location. This is very similar to the double-entry bookkeeping used for financial accounting.

### Option 1: using the API

There are several ways to obtain this information programmatically using the OpenERP API, by querying the `stock.move` model for each `stock.location`. For starters you can have a look at the [`stock.fill.inventory` wizard class](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/head:/stock/wizard/stock_fill_inventory.py#L56) of the `stock` module, which has an option to fill in the physical inventory with zeroed lines. The `product.product` model also has a `get_product_available` method that returns this information for a given set of products.

Then you can create the appropriate counterpart `stock.move` entries to achieve a balance of 0 in each location, in a way that is very similar to what the standard `stock.fill.inventory` wizard does.

### Option 2: wipe out using direct SQL

Alternatively, if you simply want to erase the whole inventory along with its history as a one-shot operation, there is a fast and dirty way. You can do it using a direct SQL query on the database (e.g. using the `psql` command-line tool or pgadmin), simply wiping out the `stock_move` and `stock_picking` tables.

**DON'T do this on a production database with real data! This will WIPE OUT a part of your database**

Assuming you have installed the Sale Management module (`sale`) and are using OpenERP 6.1, the following should work to erase the history of stock transactions and the documents their originated from:

Oh, and **make a backup** first!

```
DELETE FROM stock_move;
DELETE FROM mrp_production;
DELETE FROM stock_picking;
DELETE FROM sale_order;
DELETE FROM procurement_order;
```

Comment: I will follow the first option. Thank you very much

Comment: I think it will also take the so much time.I was using get_product_available function in the script to find the product's locations.but took a minimum of 3 hours.